# in Spring is there an application.properties by deafult?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, default, application.properties

I was trying to decompile the jar files inside Spring trying to find the default application.properties, am I wrong or it exists something like a mother file that we override.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot, the usual way to create an executable JAR file is to simply use the provided `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (or the Gradle equivalent, `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`).

By default, the structure of the JAR when created this way is as follows:

```
$ ls
my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

$ unzip my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
$ ls my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
./BOOT-INF
./META-INF
./org
```

The application configuration is, by default, located under `./BOOT-INF/classes`. Any `application.properties` (as well as other resources under `src/main/resources`) will be located there by default.

If you do not provide an `application.properties`, then sensible defaults will be used for many (but not all) components that you may be using (by e.g. including them in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` project file). In this case, no `application.properties` file will be present inside the JAR file. For example, if no `server.port` property was defined, a default of `8080` will be used to run your application.

There are many ways to configure a Spring Boot application. For the full list, including precedence of each way, see the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Answer (score 0):

There is no default `application.properties` (or `application.yaml` file) in Spring Boot. Instead, the defaults are defined in code, typically in classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. The properties that Spring Boot itself supports and their default values are [listed in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot provides various properties that can be configured in the application.properties file. The properties have default values. We can set a property(s) for the Spring Boot application. Spring Boot also allows us to define our own property if required.